# Lower current than specified with LEDs' calculations for power supply

Tags: power-supply, current, current-measurement, led-strip, ws2812b

I have 1 meter of this [ledstripe](https://www.amazon.se/dp/B09TKX6MLR) with 144 LEDs per meter. It is specified:

```
144 diodes/m = 34.56 W/m
```

That would make 6.912 A per meter. But when I connect them and have all the LEDs lit with RGB(255,255,255) and connect my multimeter in series with the power supply it only measures:

- 3.7 A - full brightness (255)
- 3.1 A - brightness set to 200
- 1.9 A -brightness set to 100

If I have something that are varying the colors in a rainbow pattern in full brightness with around 1.7 A.

How come this low current? 3.7 A max and not almost 7 A. Only half of what is specified? My plan is to connect two meters of these in series. That would result in around 7.5 A I guess maximum.

I need this of course to be able to calculate what power supply I shall by.

- Maybe a power supply like 5 V, 5 A would be enough for 1 meter.
- And 5 V, 10 A for 2 meters

Can this be correct and safe calculations?

Comment: Where's a link to the datasheet? My guess is that this is a very cheap consumer it'll-break-in-1-week kind of device, so the currents, powers and voltages will be all over the place. The link you've supplied says it's 7.2W for the meter, at 5V that's just under 1.5A, so none of these numbers stack up. Looks like it's a poor quality prodcut with no real technical information to design a real system.

Comment: I bought LED strips in Hong Kong street market back in -09 before I even saw them listed on eBay and the like, and from various sources since and I can tell you with confidence that all manufactures lie. High end ones with really expensive products lie less, low end manufactures lie more. If you buy other type of modules from brand name manufactures from reputable sellers, the product match the datasheets. I with that was the case for LED strips as well but the big guys don't seem interested in that market segment.

Comment: @Puffafish no it is probably not the best quality with a pretty low price. I am not really sure what brands though that is considered high quality. Adafruit for sure ...?

Comment: Measure the voltage at the far end of the strip and see how much you're losing passing those 3.7A through a micron-thin laser of copper.  If its a lot, hook up supply voltage to both ends and you'll see more current draw.

Answer (score 2):

If someone can sell something for more money by saying it's higher power, some people will say it's higher power.  *Caveat emptor.*

**If you've measured it, carefully, then you should trust your measurements more than any marketing statement.**

A 5A supply for LEDs you've measured at 3.9A is generally considered decent headroom.

PS. Buy your power supply from a trustworthy source.

PPS. Make sure you buy your measuring equipment from as trustworthy source as you can find.  Ideally more than one.  For trustworthy measurements, measure more than once, with different equipment.